# Outlook sent folder problem

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

Does anyone know how to change the display of my Outlook Sent Items back to "who I sent them to" instead of showing the messages are sent by me?

Answer (score 1):

Right click on a listview column header name (for example Sent), then choose "Customize Current View" then choose "Fields", then of course you would select "To" from the left side.

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is an answer to this, I want to present it in pictures to make this easier. I'm using Outlook 2013.

The archived *Sent Items* Folder was showing my name instead of showing the recipient name as shown below
[image]

To make the change go to *View* tab and select *View Settings* under the *Current View* Section.

Click on *Columns* to bring about the *Show Columns* dialog.
[image]

Follow the numbering for easy steps.

Now that you have *To* in the list of columns, just remove the *From* from the list by clicking on it and selection *Remove*.

Click OK and OK. Now all the items in your (archived) Sent items folder will be listed by the recipient name in descending order.